# Exporting Crystal report 8.5 to rtf using the Crystal Report XI engine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a bunch of Crystal Reports 8.5 reports which I need to run using the .NET Crystal Reports engine. All is fine except the fact that exporting to rtf scrambles the formatting of the report. Through many hours of testing I found out the following:

- when running the report, with no export the formatting is ok
- any export using the CR XI engine wrecks the formatting
- exporting from the CR 8.5 engine to RTF shows results scrambled in newer versions of MS Word, but correct in older versions.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I need to export from CR XI the reports made in CR 8.5 and I obviously need them to keep their formatting.

Comment: Have you tried exporting to Word? If so, what are the results?

Comment: I did, exactly the same results though.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, this looks like a dll issue to me. CR 8.5 is quite old and more and more issues are coming up with never OSs. I don't have it any more, but a quick search on the matter yielded some results.
To correct the CR 8.5 export problem you need to have two updated dll files on your client computers and registered them with regsvr32:

crtslv.dll version 8.6.1.252 or later 
exportmodeller.dll version 8.6.1.37 or later

These two files can be found in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0 or 2.5 folder after you install one of the Crystal Reports 8.5 Service Packs.

Note: crtslv.dll version 8.5.x or earlier and exportmodeller.dll version 8.5.x or earlier cannot work. The other CR files don't have to be from the Service Pack.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow morning